# jQuery UI : How can I know that the div are center on drag event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

If I have two or more divs or p tags. I want to know how can I get the center with each elements means in my fiddle example ( that I will provide below ) if I drag the the "I am title H3" ( that is my H3 tag ) to the "I am a Title H1" ( which is my H1 tag ) or to the "I am a parargraph p" ( which is my p tag ) a line that comes that indicate the two elements are center to each other.

```
var element = $(".draggable_element");

element.each(function() {
  $(this).draggable({
    zIndex: 999,
    scroll: false,
    refreshPosition: true,
  });
});
```

[Here is my fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/44ve3syv/1/)

Answer (score 0):

The below code will help you to find the center of each element on dragging. https://jsfiddle.net/44ve3syv/4/

```
var element = $(".draggable_element");
element.each(function() {
     $(this).draggable({
            zIndex: 999,
            scroll: false,
        refreshPosition: true,
        drag: function() {
         console.log(1);
        },
        stop:function(){
            checkIfCenter($(this));
        }
        });
  });
  checkIfCenter = function(el){  
    var cPos;
    var elCenter = findCentre(el);
    var isCenter = true;
    $( ".draggable_element" ).each(function() {
      cPos = findCentre($(this));
      console.log(cPos);
      if(cPos.x == elCenter.x && cPos.y == elCenter.y && isCenter){
        isCenter = true;
      }else{
        isCenter = false;
      }
    });
    if(isCenter){
        alert("All elements came in center");
    }
  }
  findCentre = function(el){
    var offset = el.offset();
    var width = el.width();
    var height = el.height();
    var pos = { x : parseInt(offset.left + width / 2),y : parseInt(offset.top + height / 2)}
    return pos;
  }
```

Comment: the fiddle is not working means the elements are not draggable

Comment: One thing when elements are in center to each other there would be some kind of line that comes when the elements are in center

Comment: You mean when all the 3 elements or any two?

Comment: All the elements, not restrected to 2 or 3 means if the example (fiddle) have more div tags or p tags or any other tags any element like suppose I want to center align my p tag to H1 and my H3 tag to p tag or h1 tag even form its left or right.

Comment: Updated the answer and the fiddle. I have used parseInt which you can remove if you want exact centre

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148578/discussion-between-vineesh-and-owaiz-yusufi).